# Limitar caracteres em uma label em uma calculadora em python usando tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, label

#display

```
app_label = Label(frame_tela, textvariable=valor_texto, width= 16, height= 2, padx=7, relief=FLAT, anchor="e", justify = RIGHT, font=('Ivy 18'), bg = cor3, fg = cor2)
app_label.place(x=0, y=0)
```

quando o usuario apertar os butões, aparece no display porém não tem limite, e fica numero infinito

Answer (score -1):

Podes limitar o número de caratéres na string que passas ao label assim:

```
limited_text = text[:10]
```

Ou então podes criar uma classe nova para a label em que passas o atributo max_length.

```
class LimitedLabel(tk.Label):
    def __init__(self, master=None, max_length=10, **kwargs):
        self.max_length = max_length
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

    def set_text(self, text):
        limited_text = text[:self.max_length]
        self.config(text=limited_text)
```